# Behaviour of fwrite

Tags: posix, standards, gnu

I assume to have a file filled with data.

If I open this file in `"r+"` mode and `seek` to any non-EOF position
and `write` one or more characters to this file, what would be the
standard result?

- In POSIX
- In GNU
- In DOS/Windows?

Would the following characters be overwritten or shifted?

If one needs an example this could be such a file:

File `a.tx`:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

C code snippet:

```
FILE * f = fopen("a.tx", "r+");
fseek(f, 5, SEEK_SET);
char * str = "12";
fwrite(str, 1, 2, f); // this is just an example
```

Comment: There is a downvote, why? How can I improve my Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very very basic I/O behavior... and not related either to POSIX, GNU or DOS/Windows, it is just standard C.

It will just write `12` at position 5 (start counting at 0), so writing `12` over `fg`. Beware that this may not be immediately visible in the file, since the write may be buffered; if you close or flush the file just after, then data will be surely written to the physical destination.

There is generally no *shifting* (you mean inserting right?) available in operating systems, while you can view it as a basic functionality, inserting something into a file necessitate too much operations to be considered as a basic OS function.

Comment: a *shift* would be `abcdefghi...` **->** `abcde12fghi...`. This is just exactly what I wanted to know, although I thought that there is a standard for this.

Comment: This is not called shift, but insertion.